# Flatlist items in the grid view size settings

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist, flatlist

I am using flatlist and i am using 2 columns the problem is that height of the items is different in every time, as it is adjusting according to content and then space is left below on every item. so i am looking for a solution so that items will be auto adjust before another item and don't maintain a scale to adjust the items.

```
<FlatList
                                numColumns={2}
                                data={filterItemClick()}
                                extraData={productsList}
                                showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
                                renderItem={({ item, index }) => renderList(item, index)}
                                ListFooterComponent={() => list_footer_component()}
                                keyExtractor={item => item.id}
                            />
```

Comment: https://github.com/brh55/react-native-masonry does this solve your problem?

Comment: @UğurEren wow this library is looking good. But can you provide me a way to implement it in the flatlist.